# Multi level menu, active links css highlight. (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, menu, helper

Site structure:

```
/
/products
/products/design
/products/photo
/about
```

I want to see **parent menu item also highlighted by CSS, when child is active.**

(When 'design' or 'photo' is active 'products' should be highlighted too.)

I'm using this for child and simple urls:

```
<li class="<%= current_page?(:action => 'design') %>">
    <%= link_to_unless_current 'Design', :design %>
</li>
```

For 'products' checking should be like:

```
<%= current_page?(:action => 'products') ||
current_page?(:action => 'design') %> ||
current_page?(:action => 'photo') %>
```

But triple || is not right, and it's become complicated.

I saw a helper, like this one:

```
def current(childs)
  if current_page?(:action => childs) 
  @container = "active"
  else
  @container = "inactive"
  end
end
```

Which is used by: `<%= current(:photo) %>`

So, how to put all my 3 checks for 'products', 'design', 'photo' in one helper?

And make possible to use something like `<%= current(:products, :design, :photo) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recreate the wheel and use a [Rails menu-builder](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_menu_builders.html) gem/plugin like [simple-navigation](http://github.com/andi/simple-navigation).

Here's a [demo of navigation and styling.](http://simple-navigation-demo.andischacke.com/)